# Traverse an n-dimensional array when dimensions are variable

Tags: algorithm, multidimensional-array

I need to traverse an n-dimensional array. The array is build and passed from another function and number of dimensions is not known in advance. This needs to be done in a primitive language similar to VBA. So, no python sort of goodness is present.

Does anyone know how this can be accomplished?

A sample array could be like a 5 x 6 x 1 x 8 array. So, it is a 4 dimensional array with dimension1=5, dimention2=6, dimension3=1 and dimension4=8.

I need to traverse each of the 5*6*1*8= 240 elements and record my results somehow so that I can relate my results with elements.

EDIT: TO make it more clear, at the end of the traversal, I want to be able to say that element at position (2,3,1,5) is x. So, I need to record the position of the element within the array and the element itself.

THe array in question is more like this

`Global multiArray as Variant

'\Now, lots of other functions, when find eligible candidates, add arrays to this array '\like below.

Redim multiarray(len(multiArray)+1)
multiArray(len(multiarray))= newElementArray()

`
So, I end up with something like below. Only that the dimensions will change at runtime, So, I need a generic logic to traverse it.
[image: Multi Jagged Array]

Comment: Do you have a foreach in that primitive language? Or a count(array) ?

Comment: Some of the language syntax you do have available would be helpful.

Comment: @radashk I do have all the usual for, while, count, substring, mid, len etc available. Guess its not too primitive :)

Comment: @DonRoby Its almost VBA. Only thing that some of the functions have been removed by them. However, it has most of the VB6 stuff available.

Answer (score 3):

Let a `coordinate` represent a location of an element in an n-dimensional array. For example `(2,1,3,4)` corresponds to an element in position: `array[2][1][3][4]`.

```
var array = // n-dimensional

function traverse(array, coordinate, dimension);
   for(var i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++){
      // assuming coordinate is immutable. Append the current iteration's index.
      currentCoordinate = coordinate.add(i); 
      if(dimension == 1){
         doSomething(currentCoordinate, array[i]);
      }else{
         traverse(array[i], currentCoordinate, dimension(array[i]));
      }      
   }
}

coordinate = []; // at first, the top level coordinate is empty.
traverse(array, coordinate, 4); // 4-dimensional
```

Comment: @greiner the solution you provided does give me traversal, yes. However, if I use this method, I lose the overall context of the element. for example, i want to be able to tell that a particular item that I printed is, say, at index (2,3,1,4). Like I added in my original question "I need to traverse each of the 5*6*1*8= 240 elements and record my results somehow so that I can relate my results with elements"

Answer (score 0):

The implementation will depend on whether it is a multi-dimensional array or a jagged array (array of arrays) as ggreiner shows.

If you only need to traverse the values of the array it can be as simple as:
(C#)

```
int[, ,] arr = new int[1, 3, 2] { { { 1, 2 }, { 3, 4 }, { 5, 6 } } };
foreach(int i in arr)
    Console.WriteLine(i);
```

Comment: thanks for introducing the term "Jagged array" fist of all :) and now I realise that I DO have a jagged array. The laguage itself supports multidimensional array but I can not declare one as I dont know the dimensions in advance. Hence I have to do with jagged arrays. So, I have a master array, and then different parts of code keep adding elements to this array, which themselves are arrays. Now, I am able to traverse this myself, similar to how @greiner explained above. However, the real pain is recording the position of it, like it were really a multidimensional array.